# Angular forEach Loop on returned data from observable (Firebase driven)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I have an observable from a service that returns an array of Payment objects, once I subscribe to my observable I perform a loop to add the amounts of each of the objects in the array. the problem I'm having that on the first load the loop is not being executed for what I assume is because the data has not yet arrived, however, if I trigger .next on the subject of the observable it workes fine.

The function of my component is like so:

```
paymentsSource = new Subject;
payments$ = this.paymentsSource.asObservable();
paymetsData:Payment[] = new Array();
totalPaymentsAmoutn:number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
  this.payments$
    .subscribe(
     (dates:{startDate:number, endDate:number}) => {
     //Here I need to performe some UTC and Locale conversion to dates thet are being passed on          
      };
      //Here I subscribe to my service          
      this.paymentService.getPaymentsByDateRange(dates.startDate, dates.endDate)
       .subscribe(
         payments => {
          this.totalPaymentsAmoutn = 0;
          this.paymetsData = payments;
          this.paymetsData.forEach( payment => {
            this.totalPaymentsAmoutn += payment.amount;
           })
          });      
       });


//this.paymentsStartDate is declear some where else but it does exist previous to this point
this.paymentsSource.next({startDate:this.paymentsStartDate, endDate:this.paymentsStartDate});

}

//This function I can triger manualy on the view
onPaymentDateRangeChanged($event){
  this.paymentsSource.next({startDate:$event.startDate, endDate:$event.endDate});
}
```

My Service function looks like this:

```
  getPaymentsByDateRange(startDate:number, endDate:number):Observable<Payment[]>{
    let paymentsArray:Payment[] = [];
    this.af.list('/bookings')
      .subscribe(
        (bookings) => {
          for(let booking of bookings){
            if(booking.payments){
              for(let payment of booking.payments){
                //condition for date range
                if(startDate <= payment.date && payment.date <= endDate){
                  payment.booking_key = booking.$key; 
                  paymentsArray.push(payment);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          //Sorting payments cronologicaly
          paymentsArray.sort(function(paymentA, paymentB){
            return paymentA.date - paymentB.date
          });
        }
      );
    return Observable.of(paymentsArray);
  }
```

When the page loads I do get the array back and the view gets populated but the value for this.totalPaymentsAmoutn remains 0, if I trigger the function manually it returns the array and updates the this.totalPaymentsAmoutn perfectly.

I am a bit new with Observables and I thought that once I subscribe to it if new data gets emitted It should run the script and update the data, I don't understand why on the first load is not working. I really think it has to do with not being able to perform the forEach loop since the array is still empty and I think that once the web sockets get connected consequent updates get push fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a disconnect in your `getPaymentsByDateRange()` method. You are returning the paymentsArray before it is populated.

```
getPaymentsByDateRange(startDate: number, endDate: number): Observable<Payment[]>{
    let paymentsArray: Payment[] = [];
    this.af.list('/bookings')
        .subscribe(...); // asynchronous
    // since this.af.list.subscribe is asynchronous, this returns before that call is finished.
    return Observable.of(paymentsArray);
}
```

You should instead return the `af.list` observable and subscribe only in the component. If you need to preprocess the data before the component uses it, you can use the rxjs .map operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // import map operator

getPaymentsByDateRange(startDate: number, endDate: number): Observable<Payment[]>{
    let paymentsArray: Payment[] = []; // you may want to move this inside the map. If you don't you may get duplicates everytime firebase emits the bookings
    return this.af.list('/bookings')
        .map(bookings => {
            for(let booking of bookings){
                if(booking.payments){
                    for(let payment of booking.payments){
                        //condition for date range
                        if(startDate <= payment.date && payment.date <= endDate){
                            payment.booking_key = booking.$key; 
                            paymentsArray.push(payment);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Sorting payments cronologicaly
            paymentsArray.sort(function(paymentA, paymentB){
                return paymentA.date - paymentB.date
            });
            return paymentsArray;
        });
}
```

This ensures that when you subscribe to this method, the onNext callback will only fire once the `af.list` observable emits.

```
 this.paymentService.getPaymentsByDateRange(dates.startDate, dates.endDate)
     .subscribe(payments => {
         // fires when af.list observable emits
     });
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this really cleared it out so easy, now I understand why it was behaving like that. One little thing I still need to do a for loop after .map to iterate through each item in the list returned by firebase.
`for(let booking of bookings){ ....`

Comment: @Xazzo good catch, I forgot to add that to my answer. updated